# If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a rational $r$ with *finite decimal expansion* s.t. $x < r < y$

Tags: real-analysis

There are many proofs (such as those described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255536/if-x-in-mathbbr-y-in-mathbbr-and-xy-then-there-exists-a-rational-r)), proving that between any two reals exists a rational: If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a rational $r$ s.t. $x < r < y$. I wish to know how these proofs can be adapted so that one can prove, in particular, that between any two reals exists a rational with **finite decimal expansion.** I have tried to adapt these proofs, using the Archemedean Principle, to end up with an expression of the form $x < n/10^k < y$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as  $n/10^k$ would certainly have a **finite decimal expansion**, but have been unsuccessful in obtaining such an inequality. How should one then adapt these proofs to show that, between any two reals exists a rational with finite decimal expansion?

Comment: Since rationals whose reduced fractional forms have denominators that are a power of $2$ (e.g. $\frac{5}{4},$ $\frac{83}{16},$ $\frac{115}{8},$ etc. -- these are called [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational)) form a subset of the set of rationals with finite decimal expansions, it is enough to prove the result for these rationals, which might be simpler to work with -- every real number is in at least one left-half or right-half of a "unit-integer interval", and also in at least one of the left-half or right-half of the previous half chosen, $\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Archimedean principle, there exists a natural number $k$ so that $\frac{1}{10^k}<b-a$ and it implies that $1<b10^k -a10^k$. This assures the existence of an integer $n$ between $a10^k$ and $b10^k$ as the gap is greater than $1$. We can mimic the proof for $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

So we have $a10^k <n < b10^k$ which implies $a< n/10^k < b$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $10^k>\frac {1}{y-x},\,$ so $\,0<10^{-k}<y-x.$

Take $A\in\Bbb Z$ such that $A\cdot 10^{-k}<x.$

There exists $j\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $(j+A)\cdot 10^{-k}\ge y .$  Let $B=\min\{j+A:j\in\Bbb Z^+\land (j+A)\cdot 10^{-k}\ge y\} .$

We have $(B-1)\cdot 10^{-k}<y.$

And we also have $$(B-1)\cdot 10^{-k}-x=$$ $$=B\cdot 10^{-k}-10^{-k}-x\ge$$ $$\ge y-10^{-k}-x=$$ $$=(y-x)-10^{-k}>0,$$ so we have

$(B-1)\cdot 10^{-k}>x.$

Comment: Intuitively, put $x,y, B\cdot 10^{-k}$ on the real line, with  $x<y\le B\cdot 10^{-k}$. If we move down from  $ B\cdot 10^{-k}$ by an amount  $10^{-k}$ to    $ (B-1)\cdot 10^{-k}$, we must still be above $x$. Otherwise we would have moved down by  at least  $y-x$, but $y-x>10^{-k}$.