# Show $\sup\{a \in D: a^2 \leq 3\} = \sqrt{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $D$ be the set of all finite decimals. I wish to show that $$\sup\{a \in D: a^2 \leq 3\} = \sqrt{3}.$$ Is the following a valid proof of the statement? It suffices to show that, $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists a \in D \text{ s.t.} \sqrt{3} - \epsilon < a.$$ However, knowing $a \in D$, so that $a \leq \sqrt{3}$, the proposition may be written as $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists a \in D \text{ s.t.} \sqrt{3} - \epsilon < a \leq \sqrt{3}.$$
So, let $\epsilon > 0$. Owing to the density of *finite* rationals in the reals (proven, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617982/if-x-y-in-mathbbr-there-exists-a-rational-r-with-finite-decimal-expan)), we are guaranteed $a \in D$ for which
$$\sqrt{3} - \epsilon < a \leq \sqrt{3}.$$

Is the proof really so simple, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is as simple as it is because you already know what is $\mathbb{R}$, so in particular $\sqrt{3}$ which is the $\sup$ (in fact it could be taken as a definition of $\sqrt{3}$).

Comment: The argument definitely uses the continuity of $x^2$. I think explicitly mentioning where this is used is helpful.

Comment: @KentaS - I'm curious where you find the continuity of $x^2$ used. The only properties of $x^2$ I see used are $\sqrt 3^2 = 3$ and that $x^2$ is increasing for $x > 0$ (used to deduce that $a^2 \le 3 \implies a \le \sqrt 3$). Both of these are more basic than continuity.

Comment: The way you've stated this problem assumes that $\sqrt 3$ exists, and all that is needed is to show that the supremum is equal to it. More commonly, the supremum of this or similar sets are used to show that there is such a number as $\sqrt 3$. That is, the theorem would be $$\left(\sup \{a\in D\mid a^2 \le 3\}\right)^2 = 3$$ Though the proof is only slightly different than what you give.

Comment: @PaulSinclair you are right, continuity is not used here. I originally thought a function like $f(x):=x$ if $x<\sqrt3$ and $f(x):=x^2$ if $x\ge\sqrt3$ provides a counter-example, but that is clearly not true.